# is there a way to regenerate R.java programming for android in eclipse?

Tags: android

I just did a clean and build on a java tutorial i am working on, and it seems the R.java file in the gen directory vanished. is there some way to tell eclipse to regenerate that file?

Originally, i was having an issue with an id in an xml file not being recognized in the findViewById(). so i did a Project/clean... to update the R.java file to include the missing id's.

to my dismay, R.java just disappeared. not instead of getting the error that the id cannot be found, i am getting an error that the variable R (of R.id.crime_title) cannot be found. not sure where to go from here.

activity_crime.xml

```
<FrameLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

---

fragment_crime.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/crime_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/crime_title_hint" /> </LinearLayout>
```

---

CrimeActivity.java

```
package com.example.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class CrimeActivity extends FragmentActivity {
//called when the activity is first created.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

    if(fragment == null){
        fragment = new CrimeFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
    }
    }
```

### }

crimeFragment.java

```
package com.example.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
private Crime mCrime;
private EditText mTitleField;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mCrime = new Crime();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, null);

    mTitleField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
    mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            mCrime.setTitle(c.toString());
        }

    });

    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code for a clear understanding of the errors your are getting?

Comment: Try removing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: i tried removing <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> and did a clean.. no luck

Comment: Can you not see any errors in your console tab?

Comment: @Zackehh9lives it says i have an error in the XML file, but i can't see where.

Comment: Is the above your entire XML contents?

Comment: yes, though currently i don't have the first line, but I'm not sure that is required. it didn't work with it in either.

Comment: The XML I can see is perfectly valid.

Comment: hmmm... i suppose for now i could just recreate the project under a new name. but after googling this issue, i have found its kind of common.

Comment: @Zackehh9lives Actually, it looks like i was missing line in my strings file. everything seems to work fine now. ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your menu bar, click

```
Project -> Clean
```

This will regenerate the `R` file, if it fails to be created, check your  output console for any XML files that failed to build correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you cleaned and it disappeared, it means it couldn't be rebuilt correctly. If you don't see any obvious red anywhere in your code, check your XML because sometimes it's extremely well hidden by Eclipse. Go through and when you're sure that it should compile, clean again and R.java will be rebuilt.

From memory, I think it will rebuild at soon as the issue is fixed automatically but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

R.java is an auto-generated file done by ADT. One can't manually generate/edit it. So if your, R.java is not getting generated, it means that there are some errors in your code (XML/Java). Please resolve them and voila, you're R.java would be generated.
If you require any help in resolving the errors, please share the errors so that we can help you out in resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i was missing a string in the strings file... that was what was causing the errors in the build. once that was added back in (i removed it as per the tutorial) everything compiled again.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `res/menu folder` there is a file `crime.xml` with an entry which is pointing to string `android:title="@string/action_settings"`.

Thus add this line in `res/values/strings.xml` in resources `<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>`. Then go to

```
menu -> project -> clean and rebuilt
```

If you have already selected `project->rebuilt` automatically, then it will automatically generate `R.java` file.

Comment: Can you clean this answer up? It's one long run-on sentence with no formatting. It's very difficult to read.